# Adding custom class to get_avatar() image doesn't work

Tags: theme-development, users, user-meta, avatar

Instead of outputting

```
<img alt="" src="#" srcset="#" class="avatar avatar-60 photo" height="60" width="60">
```

I want to add custom class which looks like

```
<img alt="" src="#" srcset="#" class="avatar avatar-60 photo myclass" height="60" width="60">
```

To achieve this, I tried to use

```
get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'], '', '', array('class' => 'myclass') );
```

However it doesn't change anything. Any help guys?

Comment: Perhaps the [`get_avatar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_avatar) filter is being run somewhere within the active theme or a plugin. This would modify the output of your call to `get_avatar()`. Try searching within the files for `get_avatar`.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( $comment, 60, '', '', $args = array( 'scheme' => 'https', 'class' => 'myclass' ) ); ?>
```

Your use of `$args['avatar_size']` should be an int and you may have confused the use of this parameter (unless you have a variable $args, and it is an array).